# Hazores hashatz for musaf, tenth left before and returns after - sources

Tags: halacha, minyan, musaf

Can we have hazaores hashatz for Musaf, if the tenth left the room before Musaf began, and then returns at the end?

In shacharis, the rational for this is based on there being someone who has not heard barchu, the kedushah, etc.., see [Orech Chaim 69](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.69?lang=bi).

Can we apply this same din and the conditions and reasoning brought there, for Musaf?

Please use sources in Shulchan Aruch and Poskim.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something so I would appreciate some clarification -- if you don't have 10, why would you think to start Chazarat Hashatz?

Comment: @rosends  See Orech Haim 69.   If the tenth arrives late for shachris, they can say the first three berachas with kedusha or even the entire tefillah out loud, depend on certain details.

Comment: @rosends the question is edited to be more clear, hopefully, thank you for asking the question